# Rapidez no cruzamento de tabelas - R

Tags: modelagem, r, merge

boa noite!

Cruzo duas bases no Rstudio,utilizando o merge, porem, gostaria de saber se utilizando outro meio de cruzamento(ex:left_join), eu consigo maior rapidez, pois minhas tabelas chegam a obter 8 milhôes de linhas.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ronaldo, tudo bem?

Veja só este experimento comparando a função merge() com a função inner_join() do pacote dplyr.

```
# Garantindo a reprodução dos resultados aleatórios
set.seed(101)

# Gerando dois datasets com 8.000.000 de observações para exemplo
df1 <- data.frame(x = sample(seq(1,16000000,1),8000000),
                  y = sample(seq(1,16000000,1),8000000),
                  z = sample(seq(1,16000000,1),8000000))

df2 <- data.frame(x = sample(seq(1,16000000,1),8000000),
                  y = sample(seq(1,16000000,1),8000000),
                  z = sample(seq(1,16000000,1),8000000))


# Testando a função merge()
system.time(dfa <- merge(df1, df2, by = c("x", "y")))

#    user  system elapsed 
# 115.911  2.563  122.016 


# Testando a função inner_join()
library(dplyr)
system.time(dfb <- inner_join(df1, df2, by = c("x", "y")))

 #   user  system elapsed 
 # 16.459   0.966  17.833
```

Observe que na minha máquina a função merge demorou 122 segundos para concluir a operação, enquanto a função inner_join demorou apenas 17 segundos.

Comment: `sample(16000000, 8000000)` é mais simples e dá os mesmos números. A **única** diferença é que a sua versão dá vetores de classe `numeric` (61Mb) e esta de classe `integer` (30.5Mb). Experimente, e teste com `identical()` e `all.equal()`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas obrigado pela dica.

Comment: Obrigado Antonio, vou alterar meu código e posto o resultado aqui.